# Rotary encoder on gpio pins in node.js vs python

Tags: gpio, node.js

I have a project where I'm connecting three small rotary encoders like these https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/pec11.pdf to a rpi 3 A+. I'm not using the button function of them, just the encoders. I have a node.js app that is reading them with the onoff gpio library. In node they seem to be spewing never-ending spurious readings without having touched the knobs. However a simple tester written in python works perfectly.

Unfortunately I'm not able to re-write my whole node app in python, so I am left asking what are the differences in these libraries or in my code that is causing the encoders to misbehave in javascript but not in python. Any help would be appreciated.

In these two tester scripts a single encoder is connected to gpio pins 17, 18 and ground.

rotarytester.js

```
const Gpio = require('onoff').Gpio;

const clkPin = 17;
const dtPin = 18;

const clk = new Gpio(clkPin, 'in', 'both');
const dt = new Gpio(dtPin, 'in', 'both');

let lastClkVal = clk.readSync();
let counter = 0;

clk.watch((err, val) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Error reading CLK pin:', err);
    return;
  }

  if (val !== lastClkVal) {
    const dtVal = dt.readSync();
    if (lastClkVal === dtVal) {
      counter++;
    } else {
      counter--;
    }

    console.log(`Encoder event: counter value: ${counter}`);
  }

  lastClkVal = val;
});

process.on('SIGINT', () => {
  console.log('Received SIGINT, terminating the app...');
  clk.unexport();
  dt.unexport();
  process.exit(0);
});

process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
  console.log('Received SIGTERM, terminating the app...');
  clk.unexport();
  dt.unexport();
  process.exit(0);
});
```

rotary tester.py

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

CLK_PIN = 17
DT_PIN = 18

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(CLK_PIN, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(DT_PIN, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

counter = 0
clkLastState = GPIO.input(CLK_PIN)

def encoder_event(channel):
    global counter, clkLastState
    dtState = GPIO.input(DT_PIN)
    clkState = GPIO.input(CLK_PIN)

    if clkState != clkLastState:
        if dtState != clkState:
            counter += 1
        else:
            counter -= 1

        print("Encoder event: counter value:", counter)
        time.sleep(0.005)  # Debounce time

    clkLastState = clkState

GPIO.add_event_detect(CLK_PIN, GPIO.BOTH, callback=encoder_event)

try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: research `pullup resistors`

Comment: This is a set of statements. It's more typical to post a question. That aside, I reckon someone may be able to figure out why it's not performing as expected. That said, if your Python works, that suggests that your hardware works, so I wonder if you might have more luck on stackoverflow?

Comment: @KDM As jsotola indicates the difference between the two is the Python contains pull-ups and the node.js does not.  Without pulls the GPIO will float between 0 and 1 (and give spurious results).

Comment: Indeed. I feel a community obligation to see that there is a distinct question being asked. I'm on the fence about it being a programming question, which is why my suggestion was politely worded. The question was answered diligently this time, but the poster may have more luck with future "questions" with a different type of community assistance.

Comment: I had some luck adding pullups using rpio like the commenter suggested, although it is still finciky enough that I may need to handle the encoders with another microcontroller connected to the pi via serial or something. Apologies for the software-centric question.

Comment: Use pigpio.  There are at least two node.js wrappers.